# Python script compiled to .exe giving error: No module named yaml

Tags: python

I can run the code below in Pycharm without issues, but when I create an exe using pyinstaller, I get the following error when I run the executable -

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openfile.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named yaml
[1296] Failed to execute script openfile**
```

```py
import yaml
from sys import exit

cfg = yaml.safe_load(open("Config.yml"))

exit()
```

Note that I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! is PyYaml contained in your exe file? how was your exe created?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? That error message seems rather straightforward, no?

Comment: What command did you use to create your exe file?

Comment: @hongsy Thanks - good to be here! :) I used the command 'pyinstaller --onefile openfile.py' to create the .exe. The answer below solved my issue. Happy, happy!

Comment: @AMC The issue was that it was working in Pycharm, but not when compiled to .exe. For a newbie with training wheels, I got stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip install pyyaml` will solve this problem

or use virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv -p python3 #or python2
virtualenv venv
venv/Scripts/activate
pip install pyyaml
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran 'pip install pyyaml', recompiled the .exe and it's now working.